# Facing trouble with Sphinx Indexer Update

Tags: mysql, sphinx, indexer

I have sphinx (version Sphinx 2.0.5-release ) running on my server. 
Recently faced a problem with indexing. 
I have a cron set which runs every 2 hours and rotates indexers. 
The problem was my Database Fields got the updated data. But their corresponding indexers failed to get the updated data. My sphinx was running and not stopped.

Is there any way to check if the indexer is updated ? Or the time it was last updated ? So that I can notify myself after every indexer rotation that the indexer is updated perfectly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to check if the indexer is updated ?

Can capture the output of indexer, and pipe it to a log file.

3 */2 * * * * indexer | ts >> /var/log/indexer

> Or the time it was last updated ?

Well can check the file dates of the index files to check when the index was regenerated. This is useful to show that for example indexer created the indexes (with .new. in filename) but searchd hasnt loaded them.

> So that I can notify myself after every indexer rotation that the indexer is updated perfectly ?

generally using the email feature of cron is pretty good. http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-crontab-change-mailto-settings/

Use --quiet with indexer, so it only outputs errors.

... but if you want something that can check the integrity, would need something application specific. Something that understands the content of data. Eg if there is is a index that updates continouslly, could run a a sphinx query, and check there are records in the last few hours. 
Or run a database query, and a sphinx query, and compare the output. Run this script regulally via cron too.